# php mysql array limit

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Okay, so I have this array. Currently it pulls multiple payment amounts and dates if multiple exist in table payments. It separates them by , as you see above. I only want it to pull the first payment date and amount. not multiple ones. Everything I've tried is breaking things at the end. Any help would be appreciated. I'm completely stumped.

```
'payment_info' => array(
    'field' => 'payment_dates, payment_amounts, recurring_amount', 
    'table' => 'LEFT JOIN 
                   (SELECT site_id, 
                       CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(start_date SEPARATOR ", ") 
                           USING latin1) AS payment_dates, 
                       CONVERT(GROUP_CONCAT(amount SEPARATOR ", ") 
                           USING latin1) AS payment_amounts 
                    FROM payments 
                    GROUP BY site_id 
                    ORDER BY start_date) AS payment_info
                ON sites.site_id = payment_info.site_id 
                LEFT JOIN 
                   (SELECT site_id, amount AS recurring_amount 
                    FROM recurring_payments 
                    GROUP BY site_id 
                    ORDER BY payment_id DESC) AS recurring_amount 
                ON sites.site_id = recurring_amount.site_id'
),
```

Here is a link to the complete file to see where query sits in array: http://pastebin.com/DiB9Z67b

Comment: That's a mighty long `'table'` value there...

Comment: Can you make it more readable - not in one line

Comment: LEFT JOIN to what? Where is the rest of the query?

Comment: Since we are not seeing the whole SELECT query or what technique/class is being used to create the query, I'm not sure how we would be able to help.

Comment: I've added link to complete file Jared, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your return $x = explode( ',', $row['payments_dates']); and use $x [0]

same with payments_amounts